# Is there a way to export latex template to scimax template?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Scimax has already some templates for various journals. However, is there a way to convert latex templates of some specific journals (like nuclear physics A, European physical journal etc.) to org-mode template? Maybe a script that does it automatically?

Those journals already have their example manuscripts. For new learners of scimax, it is difficult to create a template.  Or is there a step by step guy to create org-template from the latex-template?

For instance for the journal:
EPJA: https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/societyimages/epja/EPJA_templ.zip

Elsevier (Nuclear Physics A: https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip)

Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to help do this.  Please update your question with link(s) to any specific latex templates you would like to convert to org-mode. If the answer(s) are too detailed for this forum, I'll do my best to provide an overview which links to a public git for detailed steps.

Comment: Looks like @jkitchin provides for [ox-manuscript-templates](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/tree/master/ox-manuscript/ox-manuscript-templates). Does that help?

Comment: There is no automated way. Even I just look in the ox-manuscripts-template folder and adapt one of them to create a new one. Sometimes it is simple, and sometimes it is not.

Comment: I edited the questions with the links for the latex templates of the specific journals. It will be a great help if the template is formed so that I can write the first paper in org mode @Melioratus.

Comment: @JohnKitchin you created a stunning environment for **your research**. However, for other researchers adapting your environment can be difficult. Maybe once the number of templates are increased it would be a great starting point. Also a clear instructions while forming the template could be useful. Doing everything inside emacs is a great idea, hence, it seems that in the long run it is very efficient too. Maybe a separate scimax subtitle is necessary for stackexchange?

Comment: You can find some new templates at https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/ox-manuscript/ox-manuscript-templates/european-physics-journal.org and https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/ox-manuscript/ox-manuscript-templates/elsarticle-template.org. They might need some fine tuning still, but they mostly build to pdfs that look like the examples in those links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Summary

This `How-To` tutorial provides a step by step guide on how to migrate the LaTeX template provided by an academic journal into `org-mode` syntax.

### Instructions

To complete this tutorial successfully, please follow all steps in the order presented of each section listed below:

- Requirements
- Create New `org-mode` File
- Download LaTeX Template
- Migrate LaTeX Template Code into `file variables`
- Migrate LaTeX Template Code into `SRC` blocks
- Customize a `SRC` block using Literate Programming
- Add Content to `org-mode` File
- Export completed `org-mode` file as `PDF`

## Requirements

> **Note:** All the requirements *must* be completed successfully before continuing with the steps in this `How-To` tutorial.

### Instructions

1. Download, Install, and Configure LaTeX Software

   Unfortunately, this requirement is beyond the scope of this `How-To` tutorial.
2. Download, Install, and Configure `emacs` Software

   Unfortunately, this requirement is beyond the scope of this `How-To` tutorial.
3. Download, Install, and Configure `org-mode` Software

   > **Note:** The `org-mode` application is already installed if you are using a recent version of `emacs`, i.e. versions 25 or greater.

   Unfortunately, this requirement is beyond the scope of this `How-To` tutorial.
4. Export an `org-mode` file as `PDF` via built-in LaTeX exporter.

   > **TIP:** To export an `org-mode` document to `PDF`:
   >
   > 1. Open the `org-mode` file in `emacs`.
   > 2. Position the cursor in the buffer of the `org-mode` document in `emacs`.
   > 3. Press the following key chords and keys, `C-c` `C-e` `l` `p` to initiate the export process.
   > 4. Open the exported `PDF` file to validate the export process succeeded.

   If exporting an `org-mode` file to `PDF` succeeded then continue following the steps in this `How-To` tutorial. Otherwise troubleshoot each step in the requirements section and repeat until exporting an `org-mode` document to `PDF` is successful.

## Create New org-mode File

### Instructions

1. Create a new `org-mode` file using `emacs`.

   For this tutorial, the filename will be `journal-template.org`

   - To create the file in emacs do the following:

     1. Press the key chords `C-x` `C-f`
     2. Type `journal-template.org`
     3. Press `Return` or `Enter` key
2. Add `mode` line to top of the file.

   ```
   # -*- mode: org; org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil; org-babel-noweb-wrap-start: "«"; org-babel-noweb-wrap-end: "»"; -*-
   ```

   > **TIP:** To insert `«` press key chord `C-x` `8` `<` and to insert `»` press key chord `C-x` `8` `>`
3. Add *Template Utility Code* Section to end of file.

   ```
   * Template Utility Code                                            :noexport:
   ```
4. Add *Common Export Settings* Section to end of the file.

   ```
   * Common Export Settings                                           :noexport:

   #+OPTIONS: ':nil *:t -:t ::t <:nil H:4 \n:nil ^:{} arch:headline
   #+OPTIONS: author:nil broken-links:nil c:nil creator:nil
   #+OPTIONS: d:(not "LOGBOOK") date:nil e:t email:nil f:t inline:t num:nil
   #+OPTIONS: p:nil pri:nil prop:t stat:nil tags:t tasks:nil tex:t
   #+OPTIONS: timestamp:nil title:nil toc:nil todo:nil |:t
   #+SELECT_TAGS: export
   #+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport nolatex

   # For Display when file is exported with org-ruby 

   #+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
   #+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
   ```
5. Save the file in `emacs`.

   - To save the file in emacs do the following:

     1. Press the key chords `C-x` `C-s`

### Self Check - Example 1

After completing the instructions in this section, the contents of journal-template.org should be similar to [self-check-example-01.org](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/self-check-example-01.org).

## Download LaTeX Template

For this `How-To` tutorial, the LaTeX template<sup>1</sup> provided by the European Physical Journal A (EPJ A)<sup>2</sup> will be used.

The following 3 files provided by the EPJ A will be needed in this tutorial:

- **template.tex**

  The `template.tex` file is provided as "[a] fill-in-form for a standard article with usage comments"<sup>3</sup>.

  The objective of this `How-To` tutorial is migrate LaTeX code from `template.tex` into the new `org-mode` file.
- **svepj.clo**

  The `svepj.clo` is the LaTeX "[c]lass option file for The European Physical Journal"<sup>4</sup>.
- **svjour.cls**

  The `svjour.cls` is the LaTeX "[c]ore document class file for Springer journals"<sup>5</sup>.

### Instructions

1. Download [template.tex](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/template.tex) file into same directory as `journal-template.org`.
2. Download [svepj.clo](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/svepj.clo) file into same directory as `journal-template.org`.
3. Download [svjour.cls](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/svjour.cls) file into same directory as `journal-template.org`.

## Migrate LaTeX Template Code into `file variables`

In this section, the objective is migrate LaTeX code from LaTeX template into [file varibles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) syntax at the bottom of the `org-mode` file. The file varibles will be used when exporting from `org-mode` back to LaTeX.

The LaTeX code that will be migrated into file variables syntax is located near the top of [template.tex](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/template.tex) file:

```
%
\begin{filecontents}{leer.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%CreationDate: Mon Jul 13 16:51:17 1992
%%DocumentFonts: (atend)
%%Pages: 0 1
%%BoundingBox: 72 31 601 342
%%EndComments

gsave
72 31 moveto
72 342 lineto
601 342 lineto
601 31 lineto
72 31 lineto
showpage
grestore
%%Trailer
%%DocumentFonts: Helvetica
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass[epj]{svjour}
```

> **TIP:** When migrating the LaTeX code into `file variables`, you will need to double the backslashes `\`, e.g. `\end` will become `\\end`.

### Instructions

1. Add the following lines of file variables syntax to the end of the journal-template.org file.

   ```
   # Local Variables:
   # eval: (require (quote cl-lib))
   # eval: (require (quote ox))
   # eval: (require (quote ox-publish))
   # org-latex-with-hyperref: nil
   # eval: (add-to-list (quote org-latex-classes) (quote ("epj-svjour" "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% epj-svjour %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   # %
   # \\begin{filecontents}{leer.eps}
   # %!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
   # %%CreationDate: Mon Jul 13 16:51:17 1992
   # %%DocumentFonts: (atend)
   # %%Pages: 0 1
   # %%BoundingBox: 72 31 601 342
   # %%EndComments
   # 
   # gsave
   # 72 31 moveto
   # 72 342 lineto
   # 601 342 lineto
   # 601 31 lineto
   # 72 31 lineto
   # showpage
   # grestore
   # %%Trailer
   # %%DocumentFonts: Helvetica
   # \\end{filecontents}
   # %
   # \\documentclass[epj]{svjour}
   #  [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
   #  [PACKAGES]
   #  [EXTRA]" ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}") ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}") ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}") ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}") ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
   # End:
   ```
2. Add the following line under the mode line near the top of the journal-template.org file.

   ```
   #+LATEX_CLASS: epj-svjour
   ```

### Self Check - Example 2

After completing the instructions in this section, the contents of journal-template.org should be similar to [self-check-example-02.org](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/self-check-example-02.org).

## Migrate LaTeX Template Code into `SRC` blocks

In this section, the object is to migrate specific snippets of LaTeX code from the LaTeX template into `SRC` block syntax provided by `org-mode`. Each `SRC` block will inject customized LaTeX into the final LaTeX document created by the built-in exporter.

These template specific `SRC` blocks will be kept under a dedicated section named `Template Utility Code` which will not be exported.

### Instructions

1. Add the following lines **after** the `* Template Utility Code` section in the journal-template.org document.

   ```
   ** export-epj-latex-block

    #+NAME: export-epj-latex-block
    #+BEGIN_SRC latex :noweb yes
      %
      \title{«get-title-text()»}
      \subtitle{«get-subtitle-text()»}
      \author{«epj-authors-latex()»% etc
      % \thanks is optional - remove next line if not needed
      \thanks{\emph{Present address:} Insert the address here if needed}%
      }                     % Do not remove
      %
      \offprints{}          % Insert a name or remove this line
      %
      \institute{«epj-institutions-latex()»}
      %
      \date{Received: date / Revised version: date}
      % The correct dates will be entered by Springer
      %
      \abstract{
      «get-abstract-text()»
      %
      \PACS{
      «epj-pacs-codes-latex()»
       } % end of PACS codes
      } %end of abstract
      %
      \maketitle
    #+END_SRC

   *** get-title-text

    #+NAME: get-title-text
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp 
      (format "%s" (car (plist-get (org-export-get-environment) ':title)))
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: get-title-text
    : Title Goes Here

   *** get-subtitle-text

    #+NAME: get-subtitle-text
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp  :results replace :var keyword="subtitle" :var delimiter=" "
     (mapconcat 'car (org-element-map
          (org-element-parse-buffer)
          '(keyword)
        (lambda (x) (if (string= (upcase keyword) (org-element-property :key x))
             (list (org-element-property :value x)) )
          )
        ) delimiter)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: get-subtitle-text
    : Subtitle Goes Here

   *** get-abstract-text

    #+NAME: get-abstract-text
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results replace :var keyword="abstract"
      (org-element-map (org-element-map
               (org-element-parse-buffer)
               '(headline)
                 (lambda (hl) (if (string= (upcase keyword) (upcase (org-element-property :raw-value hl)))
                         hl)
               ) 
                 nil t)
          '(paragraph)
        (lambda (p) 
          (format "%s" (replace-regexp-in-string (rx (or (: bos (* (any " \t\n")))
                                 (: (* (any " \t\n")) eos)))
                             ""
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties (org-element-property :contents-begin p) (org-element-property :contents-end p))))
          )
        nil t)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: get-abstract-text
    : The abstract goes here.

   *** epj-pacs-codes-latex 

    #+NAME: epj-pacs-codes-latex
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp  :var pacs_codes=pacs-codes-table :results latex replace :var join_delim="   \\and\n"
      (mapconcat 'identity (mapcar (lambda (x) (format "      {%s}{%s}" (car x) (nth 1 x))) pacs_codes) join_delim)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: epj-pacs-codes-latex
    #+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
          {PACS-key01}{Text Describing PACS-key01}   \and
          {PACS-key02}{Text Describing PACS-key02}
    #+END_EXPORT

   *** epj-authors-latex 

    #+NAME: epj-authors-latex
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp  :var authors=authors-table :results latex replace :var join_delim=" \\and "
      (mapconcat 'identity (mapcar (lambda (x) (format "%s\\inst{%s}" (car x) (nth 2 x))) authors) join_delim)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: epj-authors-latex
    #+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
    Mai Deah\inst{1} \and Arthur Secondus\inst{1} \and E. Tal\inst{2}
    #+END_EXPORT

   *** epj-institutions-latex 

    #+NAME: epj-institutions-latex
    #+BEGIN_SRC elisp  :var institutions=institutions-table :results latex replace :var join_delim=" \\and "
      (mapconcat 'identity (mapcar (lambda (x) (format "%s" (nth 1 x))) institutions) join_delim)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: epj-institutions-latex
    #+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
    New Discoveries Lab, Department of Something-or-Ruther, University of Some-Sort, Some-Sort, Some-Sort-of-Country \and Golden Opportunities Lab, Department of Obscure Studies, Ancient College, Olde-Locale, Stodgy-Land
    #+END_EXPORT
   ```
2. Add the following lines **before** the `* Template Utitily Code` section in the journal-template.org document.

   ```
   #+TITLE: Title Goes Here

   #+SUBTITLE: Subtitle Goes Here

   #+CALL: export-epj-latex-block()

   * Authors                                                          :nolatex:

   #+NAME: authors-table
   | Author          | Email                | Institution-ID |
   |-----------------+----------------------+----------------|
   | Mai Deah        | mai.deah@example.edu |              1 |
   | Arthur Secondus |                      |              1 |
   | E. Tal          |                      |              2 |

   * Institutions                                                     :nolatex:

   #+NAME: institutions-table
   | Institution-ID | Institution                                                                                                      |
   |----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |              1 | New Discoveries Lab, Department of Something-or-Ruther, University of Some-Sort, Some-Sort, Some-Sort-of-Country |
   |              2 | Golden Opportunities Lab, Department of Obscure Studies, Ancient College, Olde-Locale, Stodgy-Land               |

   * PACS                                                             :nolatex:

   #+NAME: pacs-codes-table
   | PACS-KEY   | PACS-KEY-Description-Text  |
   |------------+----------------------------|
   | PACS-key01 | Text Describing PACS-key01 |
   | PACS-key02 | Text Describing PACS-key02 |

   * Abstract                                                         :nolatex:

   # The abstract goes here.
   ```

### Self Check - Example 3

After completing the instructions in this section, the contents of journal-template.org should be similar to [self-check-example-03.org](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/self-check-example-03.org).

## Add Content to `org-mode` File

In this section, several new placeholder sections will added. The content of each section will be `Lorem Ipsum`

### Instructions

1. Add content to journal-template.org.

   > The migration to journal-template.org is complete. Adding **real** content will be left as an exercise for the reader.

### Self Check - Example 4 - Part I

After completing the instructions in this section, the contents of journal-template.org should be similar to [self-check-example-04.org](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/self-check-example-04.org).

## Export completed `org-mode` file as `PDF`

In this section, the objective is to export the org-mode template to LaTeX and create a `PDF`.

### Instructions

1. Export an `org-mode` file as `PDF` via built-in LaTeX exporter.

   To export an `org-mode` document to `PDF`:

   1. Open the `org-mode` file in `emacs`.
   2. Position the cursor in the buffer of the `org-mode` document in `emacs`.
   3. Press the following key chords and keys, `C-c` `C-e` `l` `p` to initiate the export process.
   4. Open the exported `PDF` file to validate the export process succeeded.

### Self Check - Example 4 - Part II

After completing the instructions in this section, the contents of journal-template.org should be similar to [self-check-example-04.pdf](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/self-check-example-04.pdf).

> **Note:** The LaTeX file created during the export should be similar to [self-check-example-04.tex](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/self-check-example-04.tex).

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/societyimages/epja/EPJA_templ.zip

<sup>2</sup> https://epja.epj.org/

<sup>3</sup> Description text for template.tex provided by EPJ A in `read.me` instructions.

<sup>4</sup> Description text for svepj.clo provided by EPJ A in `read.me` instructions.

<sup>5</sup> Description text for svjour.cls provided by EPJ A in `read.me` instructions.

---

> **This answer was validated using:**
>   **emacs:** GNU Emacs 26.1
>   **org-mode:** 9.1.14

Answer (score 2):

To use a specific journal template in Org Mode you need to create a LaTeX class. This is what I use in my init file for Springer journals:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes '("Springer"
               "\\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3}
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

To use this setup in your org file, reference the name you gave it.

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: Springer
```

All you have to do is to install the appropriate files in LaTeX, update your init file in Emacs. Example using the APA template is here: https://github.com/pprevos/r.prevos.net/tree/master/Miscellaneous/BodyImage