# How can I **completely** migrate a LaTeX template to an Org file?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I've written my own LaTeX class file that deals with page layouts, title styles, subheading styles and uses `fancyhdr` so that each page has the section name and document title in the header, and so forth. (And I do the whole `(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes '("my_class_name ..."` as required.)

Doing this, I've managed to make a nice `.org` file which I use as the `SETUPFILE` for any document I want to export into a `pdf` via LaTeX.

This works perfectly fine, but I wonder if I can be a bit more ambitious, and move the **entire** class setup into an `.org` file that I can use, without calling my custom class (i.e. I will only use `#+LaTeX_HEADER:\documentclass{article}` or `#+LaTeX_HEADER:\LoadClass{article}` as the base class to modify).

This [nice answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46848/24188) and [this expanded procedure](https://github.com/Literate-DevOps/literate-programming-tutorials/blob/master/how-to/00-convert-latex-template-into-org-mode-template/how-to-migrate-latex-template-into-org-mode.org) by @Melioratus is *not quite* what I would like to do - at the end of the day, the (non-standard) LaTeX class file still needs the `svjour.cls` file  to be present (at least as far as I can tell). I basically want to do away with `svjour.cls` entirely, and re-write it as an org file (albeit in my case the code is much simpler).

As an example of the code from the template I would like to migrate to org is the block:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  % \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{--~\thepage~--}} % except the center
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%\renewcommand
  % {\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\quad #1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\@title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{-- ~\thepage ~ --}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
}
```

Unfortunately, copying it into a LaTeX source block/ including it in several `#+LaTeX_HEADER`s doesn't work -- the title, subsection name variables don't seem to be passed properly.

Comment: My recommendation would be to *NOT* do that: Org mode does not know much LaTeX and the exporter is limited in what it can produce. So having your own class file and using `#+LATEX_CLASS: ` is the way to go IMO.

Comment: @NickD noted! I am just trying to see how far we can push the principle of keeping everything in `emacs`/`org`.

Comment: What about having the exporter tangle a file, then include that file. Does that meet your requirements, or is that too 'external'?

Comment: @mankoff That sounds useful! Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024520/can-org-mode-tangle-during-export ?